# What flaws go with the Sandman predator type?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

In **Vampire: the Masquerade Fifth Edition**, vampires take Predator Types to show the ways they are accustomed to feeding. These packages come with a discipline dot, a skill specialization, some Merits or Backgrounds, and a number of Flaws or other drawbacks to balance them out. The exception is the Sandman predator type — it has no flaws as part of its description.

1. Is this an error? That is, should there be flaws listed that simply did not make it to print? If so, what are these missing flaws?
2. If it's not an error, what flaws would best suit this predator type, were one to assign some? A good answer would select several flaws from published V5 material and explain why they reflect the troubles inherent to the Sandman predator type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an error, no.

The "standard" package for a Predator Type in V5 is:

- One specialty or skill dot
- One discipline dot
- X dots of merits or backgrounds
- X-1 dots of flaws

The Sandman gains only one dot of merits/backgrounds, so it gains zero dots of flaws.

Answer (score 3):

To answer to the point 1, since there is no rules errata (or at least I didn't found it, but modiphius give the core book errata for free, so if you have a doubt, you can go [there](https://www.modiphius.net/collections/vampire-the-masquerade/products/vampire-5th-edition-core-book-errata) to download it) about the Sandman predator type, we can say that it's not an error.

To answer to the point 2, the sandman description read: (core book, p177)

> You rely on your stealth or Disciplines to feed from
>   sleeping victims. If they never wake during the feeding,
>   they won’t know you exist. Perhaps you were very
>   anti-social in life; you don’t feel cut out for the intense
>   interpersonal nightlife or physical violence of more
>   extroverted hunters.

If we focus on the "If they never wake during the feeding, they won’t know you exist" sentence, you can see that a *Prey Exclusion: awaken person* or *Prey Exclusion: peoples who know that I exist* flaw might be relevant, and if we focus on the "Perhaps you were very anti-social in life" we can use the *infamy (.)* flaw by the fact that anti-social might be hatefull peoples (not always, but sometimes that's why they end up as anti-social) or any other "social malus" flaw.